# JavaScript output to innerHTML cuts off background image down page

Tags: javascript, css, image, background

http://www.hamdenway.co.uk/portfoliojavascript.html

I am building a website portfolio for applying for apprenticeships. I made a generator with JavaScript which prints out results in a list through output.innerHTML.

It all works fine but when it prints off the page, the background image cuts off. I want the background image to continue repeating for the new content.

In Brackets in my stylesheet I am hovering over body {} and it doesn't update the height for the newly generated content. I thought it would do this as:

```
    body {
    background-image:url('../portfolioimages/yellowbg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin:0px;
    }
```

So result is this horrible cut-off of the background image. If you need any more code please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` from body css. Just open the console of browser and remove the height to test it

```
body {
    background-image:url('../portfolioimages/yellowbg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much! This has been bugging me for days.

I removed the height:100% and it made the background stop halfway BEFORE user had entered any numbers, but adding a bit of padding to the bottom got rid of that. Appreciate the help!